# PHP foreach loop through multidimensional array output group by one key->value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have the following array with day and totalprice:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [day] => 01/08/2019 [totalprice] => 585.00 ) 
[1] => Array ( [day] => 02/08/2019 [totalprice] => 585.00 ) 
[2] => Array ( [day] => 03/08/2019 [totalprice] => 585.00 ) 
[3] => Array ( [day] => 04/08/2019 [totalprice] => 585.00 ) 
[4] => Array ( [day] => 05/08/2019 [totalprice] => 585.00 ) 
[5] => Array ( [day] => 06/08/2019 [totalprice] => 585.00 ) 
[6] => Array ( [day] => 07/08/2019 [totalprice] => 585.00 ) 
[7] => Array ( [day] => 08/08/2019 [totalprice] => 585.00 ) 
[8] => Array ( [day] => 09/08/2019 [totalprice] => 585.00 ) 
[9] => Array ( [day] => 10/08/2019 [totalprice] => 585.00 ) 
[10] => Array ( [day] => 11/08/2019 [totalprice] => 585.00 ) 
[11] => Array ( [day] => 12/08/2019 [totalprice] => 585.00 ) 
[12] => Array ( [day] => 13/08/2019 [totalprice] => 585.00 ) 
[13] => Array ( [day] => 14/08/2019 [totalprice] => 585.00 ) 
[14] => Array ( [day] => 15/08/2019 [totalprice] => 585.00 ) 
[15] => Array ( [day] => 16/08/2019 [totalprice] => 585.00 ) 
[16] => Array ( [day] => 17/08/2019 [totalprice] => 585.00 ) 
[17] => Array ( [day] => 18/08/2019 [totalprice] => 585.00 ) 
[18] => Array ( [day] => 19/08/2019 [totalprice] => 585.00 ) 
[19] => Array ( [day] => 20/08/2019 [totalprice] => 585.00 ) 
[20] => Array ( [day] => 21/08/2019 [totalprice] => 585.00 ) 
[21] => Array ( [day] => 22/08/2019 [totalprice] => 585.00 ) 
[22] => Array ( [day] => 23/08/2019 [totalprice] => 585.00 ) 
[23] => Array ( [day] => 24/08/2019 [totalprice] => 585.00 ) 
[24] => Array ( [day] => 25/08/2019 [totalprice] => 585.00 ) 
[25] => Array ( [day] => 26/08/2019 [totalprice] => 585.00 ) 
[26] => Array ( [day] => 27/08/2019 [totalprice] => 585.00 ) 
[27] => Array ( [day] => 28/08/2019 [totalprice] => 585.00 ) 
[28] => Array ( [day] => 29/08/2019 [totalprice] => 585.00 ) 
[29] => Array ( [day] => 30/08/2019 [totalprice] => 585.00 ) 
[30] => Array ( [day] => 31/08/2019 [totalprice] => 585.00 ) 
[31] => Array ( [day] => 01/09/2019 [totalprice] => 410.00 ) 
[32] => Array ( [day] => 02/09/2019 [totalprice] => 410.00 ) 
[33] => Array ( [day] => 03/09/2019 [totalprice] => 0.00 ) 
[34] => Array ( [day] => 04/09/2019 [totalprice] => 0.00 ) 
[35] => Array ( [day] => 05/09/2019 [totalprice] => 0.00 ) 
[36] => Array ( [day] => 06/09/2019 [totalprice] => 0.00 ) 
[37] => Array ( [day] => 07/09/2019 [totalprice] => 0.00 ) 
[38] => Array ( [day] => 08/09/2019 [totalprice] => 0.00 ) 
[39] => Array ( [day] => 09/09/2019 [totalprice] => 0.00 ) 
[40] => Array ( [day] => 10/09/2019 [totalprice] => 0.00 ) 
[41] => Array ( [day] => 11/09/2019 [totalprice] => 0.00 ) 
[42] => Array ( [day] => 12/09/2019 [totalprice] => 0.00 ) 
[43] => Array ( [day] => 13/09/2019 [totalprice] => 0.00 ) 
[44] => Array ( [day] => 14/09/2019 [totalprice] => 0.00 ) 
[45] => Array ( [day] => 15/09/2019 [totalprice] => 0.00 ) 
[46] => Array ( [day] => 16/09/2019 [totalprice] => 0.00 ) 
[47] => Array ( [day] => 17/09/2019 [totalprice] => 410.00 ) 
[48] => Array ( [day] => 18/09/2019 [totalprice] => 410.00 ) 
[49] => Array ( [day] => 19/09/2019 [totalprice] => 410.00 ) 
[50] => Array ( [day] => 20/09/2019 [totalprice] => 410.00 ) 
[51] => Array ( [day] => 21/09/2019 [totalprice] => 410.00 ) 
[52] => Array ( [day] => 22/09/2019 [totalprice] => 410.00 ) 
[53] => Array ( [day] => 23/09/2019 [totalprice] => 410.00 ) 
[54] => Array ( [day] => 24/09/2019 [totalprice] => 410.00 ) 
[55] => Array ( [day] => 25/09/2019 [totalprice] => 410.00 ) 
[56] => Array ( [day] => 26/09/2019 [totalprice] => 410.00 ) 
[57] => Array ( [day] => 27/09/2019 [totalprice] => 410.00 ) 
[58] => Array ( [day] => 28/09/2019 [totalprice] => 410.00 ) 
[59] => Array ( [day] => 29/09/2019 [totalprice] => 410.00 ) 
[60] => Array ( [day] => 30/09/2019 [totalprice] => 410.00 ) 
[61] => Array ( [day] => 01/10/2019 [totalprice] => 235.00 ) 
[62] => Array ( [day] => 02/10/2019 [totalprice] => 235.00 ) 
[63] => Array ( [day] => 03/10/2019 [totalprice] => 235.00 ) 
[64] => Array ( [day] => 04/10/2019 [totalprice] => 235.00 ) 
[65] => Array ( [day] => 05/10/2019 [totalprice] => 235.00 ) 
[66] => Array ( [day] => 06/10/2019 [totalprice] => 235.00 ) 
[67] => Array ( [day] => 07/10/2019 [totalprice] => 235.00 ) 
[68] => Array ( [day] => 08/10/2019 [totalprice] => 235.00 ) 
[69] => Array ( [day] => 09/10/2019 [totalprice] => 235.00 ) 
[70] => Array ( [day] => 10/10/2019 [totalprice] => 235.00 ) 
[71] => Array ( [day] => 11/10/2019 [totalprice] => 235.00 ) 
[72] => Array ( [day] => 12/10/2019 [totalprice] => 235.00 ) 
[73] => Array ( [day] => 13/10/2019 [totalprice] => 235.00 ) 
[74] => Array ( [day] => 14/10/2019 [totalprice] => 235.00 ) 
[75] => Array ( [day] => 15/10/2019 [totalprice] => 235.00 ) 
[76] => Array ( [day] => 16/10/2019 [totalprice] => 235.00 ) 
[77] => Array ( [day] => 17/10/2019 [totalprice] => 235.00 ) 
[78] => Array ( [day] => 18/10/2019 [totalprice] => 235.00 ) 
[79] => Array ( [day] => 19/10/2019 [totalprice] => 235.00 ) 
[80] => Array ( [day] => 20/10/2019 [totalprice] => 235.00 ) 
[81] => Array ( [day] => 21/10/2019 [totalprice] => 235.00 ) 
[82] => Array ( [day] => 22/10/2019 [totalprice] => 235.00 ) 
[83] => Array ( [day] => 23/10/2019 [totalprice] => 235.00 ) 
[84] => Array ( [day] => 24/10/2019 [totalprice] => 235.00 ) 
[85] => Array ( [day] => 25/10/2019 [totalprice] => 235.00 ) 
[86] => Array ( [day] => 26/10/2019 [totalprice] => 235.00 ) 
[87] => Array ( [day] => 27/10/2019 [totalprice] => 235.00 ) 
[88] => Array ( [day] => 28/10/2019 [totalprice] => 235.00 ) 
[89] => Array ( [day] => 29/10/2019 [totalprice] => 235.00 ) 
[90] => Array ( [day] => 30/10/2019 [totalprice] => 235.00 ) 
[91] => Array ( [day] => 31/10/2019 [totalprice] => 235.00 )
)
```

With the following code :

```
foreach($blankarray as $rate){

    if ($rate['totalprice'] == '0'){
    } else {
        $firstrate = $rate['totalprice'];
        if ($firstrate != $previousrate) {
            $firstdate = $rate['day'];
            echo '<br>'.$firstdate; 
            echo '</br><font color="green"> <b>'.$firstrate .'</b></font>';
            $previousrate = $firstrate;
        }
```

I get:

```
01/08/2019
585.00
01/09/2019
410.00
01/10/2019
235.00
```

How can I add the previous date when totalprice is changing so I can have :

```
01/08/2019
31/08/2019
585.00
01/09/2019
30/09/2019
410.00
01/10/2019
31/10/2019
235.00
```

Comment: Where are 410.00 and 235.00 in the input data?

Comment: What is the logic of your desired output?  I don't see how it relates at all to your sample input

Comment: I edited out the 500 lines of the array so you'll have to use your imagination :(

Comment: The question says to do something when the price changes. But the price never changes.

Comment: We don't need 500 lines, but we need something that reflects the actual problem.

Comment: it goes on [32] => Array ( [day] => 01/09/2019 [totalprice] => 410.00 ) [61] => Array ( [day] => 01/10/2019 [totalprice] => 235.00 )

Comment: Please make the array readable, not all on one line, so we can see where the price changes.

Comment: The desired output looks like you just want the first and last day or each month.

Comment: You could add an index to the for loop (`foreach($blankarray as $key => $rate)`). This will give you a quick way to access the previous index (`$previous = $key-1; $lastprice = $blankarray[$previous]['totalprice']`).

Comment: @Barmar: Rolled back and edited. It was only 87.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will give you the results you want. It checks whether the current price in the array is not equal to either the previous price or the next price (ignoring all `0` values), and if so, it outputs the price:

```
$previousprice = -1;
$thisprice = -1;
$nextprice = $blankarray[0]['totalprice'];
$c = count($blankarray);
for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
    $previousprice = $thisprice;
    $thisprice = $nextprice;
    $nextprice = ($i == $c - 1) ? -1 : $blankarray[$i+1]['totalprice'];
    if ($previousprice == 0 || $thisprice == 0 || $nextprice == 0) continue;
    if ($thisprice != $previousprice) {
        echo '<br>'.$blankarray[$i]['day']; 
    }
    if ($thisprice != $nextprice) {
        echo '<br>'.$blankarray[$i]['day']; 
        echo '<br><font color="green"> <b>'.$blankarray[$i]['totalprice'].'</b></font>' . "\n";        
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<br>01/08/2019<br>31/08/2019<br><font color="green"> <b>585</b></font> 
<br>01/09/2019<br>30/09/2019<br><font color="green"> <b>410</b></font> 
<br>01/10/2019<br>31/10/2019<br><font color="green"> <b>235</b></font>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/39OTA)

Comment: Thank you for this. Can I make it look like
01/08/2019
31/08/2019
585.00
01/09/2019
30/09/2019
410.00
01/10/2019
31/10/2019
235.00

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, I renamed your array to $rates and switched to a for loop.

```
$rates_count = sizeof($rates);
$previous = 1;
for($i = 1; $i < $rates_count; ++$i) {
    if($rates[$i]['totalprice'] !== 0) {
        if($rates[$i]['totalprice'] > $rates[$previous]['totalprice']) {
            echo
                '<br />', "\n",
                $rates[$i]['day'], "\n",
                '<br />', "\n",
                $rates[$previous]['day'], "\n",
                '<br />', "\n",
                '<span style="color: green; font-weight: bold;">', $rates[$i]['totalprice'], '</span>', "\n";
            $previous = $i;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the previous date and price in a variable. Whenever the price changes, print the previous date, the previous price, and the current date.

```
$prev_date = null
foreach ($blankarray as $rate) {
    if ($rate['totalprice'] == 0) {
        // ignore zero rows
        continue;
    }
    if ($rate['day'] != $prev_date) {
        if ($prev_date) {
            echo "$prev_date<br><span style='color: green;'>$prev_price</span><br>";
        }
    }
    $prev_date = $rate['date'];
    $prev_price = $rate['totalprice'];
    echo $rate['date'] . "<br>";
}
// End the last group
echo "$prev_date<br><span style='color: green;'>$prev_price</span><br>";
```